# Dual Fantasy Novellas about Sleeping Gods and Robots

Tags: story-identification, novella

This was a book with two novellas.  Both novellas used the same main characters but each was written by a different author.  The original novella had the characters run into a sleeping god and the robots he created to run the world for him.  The robots were planning a revolt.  The characters woke the god up and he killed the robots.  I can't remember the second novella, but I do know it was a prequel to the original.  I think the novellas were printed upside down to each other, i.e., to read the second you had to turn the book over and flip it around.

Comment: Lots of "paired novels" mentioned here; http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?p=19793351

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of Ace double books: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ace_double_titles  If you know the year you read your book, you might be able to look for familiar titles in the list.

Comment: Thank you, tried both those sources but didn't find what I was looking for.  The Ace titles seem to end well before I read this book in 93-95.

Comment: Maybe a Tor double? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_Double_Novels

Comment: Yep, that helped.  It is The Jewel of Bas/Thieves' Carnival.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the above comment, I found the book I was looking for.  It is *The Jewel of Bas/Thieves' Carnival*.  Thank you!

[image]